# Problem with saving data in ManyToMany tables, hibernate, spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, many-to-many

Below - parent table - users:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username", length = 50, unique = true)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 4, max = 50)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password", length = 100)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 4, max = 100)
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    private List<Role> roles;


//constructor, getters/setters
```

Below You can find table with roles:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 50)
    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private RoleName name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<User> users;

//constructor, getters/setters
```

And I will try save User by belows method:

```
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private Session session;


    @Override
    public void saveUser(User user) {
        Role role = getRoleByName(RoleName.ROLE_ADMIN);
        user.getRoles().add(role );
        role.getUsers().add( user );
        session.persist(user);
    }

    public Role getRoleByName(RoleName name) {

        Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT r FROM Role r WHERE r.name= :name");
        query.setParameter("name", name);
        return (Role) query.uniqueResult();
    }
```

But I have two problems:
- first - the main problem - I did something wrong and I can't save new user.
- second one - I have null result in quer result in getRoleByName, but of course, that role exists in table user_roles.

And any solution will be perfect for me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: use `user.getRoles.add( role )` and `role.getUsers.add( user )`

Comment: the SQL statement is wrong : "SELECT r FROM Role r WHERE r.name= :name"

Comment: Thank you so much. I was edited my question. But still I have no any result. NullPointer exception from query in getRoleByName method.